# How to include ngCordova plugins in my ionic app?

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic-framework

I want to add Cordova plugins into my ionic app. But it seems that it isn't working.

I will walk you through the steps I took:

1. Added cordova plugins in the plugins folder.
2. Included ng-cordova.min.js file in index.html before codova.js
3. Injected ngCordova in app.js
4. Injected the required plugin in my controller ( $cordovaBarcodeScanner in this case)

Can someone please help me with that?

Comment: yes, I did. thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the plugin with

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git
```

then use the plugin in your page like this

```
module.controller('BarcodeCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaBarcodeScanner) {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

  $cordovaBarcodeScanner
    .scan()
    .then(function(barcodeData) {
      // Success! Barcode data is here
    }, function(error) {
      // An error occurred
    });
)};
```

This example and more information are available at http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/barcodeScanner/

See also https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/implement-barcode-scanner-using-ionic-framework/

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the cordova cli command to install the barcodeScanner plugin? something like:

```
$ cordova plugin add <plugin url>
```

Comment: Hi, 
Yes, I ran this command which added the required plugin in the plugins folder. 
Do, I have to do anything else to install the plugin?

Comment: Well, it would be helpful to show some code, can you post some?